# Stopping spark steaming context on encountering certain message on Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In my Spark Streaming application I am reading data from certain Kafka topic. While reading from topic whenever I encounter certain message (for example: "poison") I want to stop the streaming. Currently I am achieving this using following code: 
`jsc` is instance of JavaStreamingContext and `directStream` is instance of JavaPairInputDStream.

```
LongAccumulator poisonNotifier = sc.longAccumulator("poisonNotifier");

directStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            RDD<Row> rows = rdd.values().map(value -> {              
                if (value.equals("poison") {
                    poisonNotifier.add(1);
                } else {
                    ... 
                }
                return row;
            }).rdd();
        });

jsc.start();
ExecutorService poisonMonitor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
poisonMonitor.execute(() -> {
    while (true) {
        if (poisonNotifier.value() > 0) {
            jsc.stop(false, true);
            break;
        }
    }
});
try {
    jsc.awaitTermination();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
poisonMonitor.shutdown();
```

Although this approach is working, this doesn't sounds like right approach to me. Is there any other better(cleaner) way to achieve the same?

Comment: I'm curious if you had to use the volatile technique for checkpoints mentioned here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-broadcast-variables-and-checkpoints